# Why the graph of $\sin(\sin^{-1}(x))$ is the identity?

Tags: functions, inverse-function, mathematica

I just made the following plots on Mathematica:

> [image]

This may be really silly but I don't understand why the plot of $\sin(\sin^{-1}(x))$ is the identity. Isn't $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is defined only on the interval $[-1,1]$? How come it has values outside of that interval? [Here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Inverse_functions), it says:

> *The trigonometric functions are periodic, and hence not injective, so strictly speaking, they do not have an inverse function. However, on each interval on which a trigonometric function is monotonic, one can define an inverse function, and this defines inverse trigonometric functions as multivalued functions. To define a true inverse function, one must restrict the domain to an interval where the function is monotonic, and is thus bijective from this interval to its image by the function. The common choice for this interval, called the set of principal values, is given in the following table.*

So is Mathematica using more than one set of principal values? I'm confused.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mathematica, but according to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcSin.html it works in the complex domain, and then $\sin^{-1}(x)$ has (some) value for arbitrary (real) arguments.

Comment: On Desmos this is a bit different: the graph is still an identity, but it's only defined on $[-1, 1]$

Comment: @MartinR With your suggestion, I made the following [plot](https://i.imgur.com/XY5fxx6.png) where I compute real and imaginary parts at both places in the function and it just got weirder, I guess.

Comment: @The2nd Perhaps this is true, I thought I was doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sine function maps the real axis onto the interval $[-1, 1]$, but it maps the complex plane onto itself. From
$$
 \sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
it is not difficult to see that the equation $\sin(z) = w$ has (infinitely many) solutions for every $w \in \Bbb C$.

`ArcSin[z]` is defined for arbitrary complex values $z$ (the precise formula is given in the [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcSin.html)) and returns some (complex) number such that `Sin[ArcSin[z]] == z`.

Comment: What is troubling is that the complex values should not appear in this kind of plot. For example: I made a plot of $\sqrt{x}$ in $[-1,1]$, see [here](https://i.imgur.com/ubrerSA.png). The complex values do not appear in the plot. Now if I ask Mathematica to plot $\sqrt{x}$ and $\Im{(\sqrt(x))}$, I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/P9x3AzU.png). I think this plot accepts only real values.

Comment: @BillyRubina: If $x > 1$ then `ArcSin[x]` evaluates to a complex number, but `Sin[ArcSin[x]]` evaluates to a *real* number (namely, $x$). Therefore no complex numbers do appear when plotting `Sin[ArcSin[x]]` over the real axis. – It is the same with $\Im{(\sqrt(x))}$, which evaluates to a real number for all $x \in \Bbb R$.